# yii update and insert scenarios rules

Tags: php, yii

I have tried using yii scenarios to separate my rules between update and creating a new record. when I put the scenarios like below, the record doesn't validate the form and the scenarios are not working. I wonder where am going wrong

```
return array(
            array('first_name, second_name, username, password, email, skype, attachment, just, cv', 'required','on'=>'insert'),
           array('first_name, second_name, username, password, email', 'required','on'=>'update'),
            array('first_name, second_name, username, password, email, skype, status, attachment, just, cv', 'length', 'max'=>255),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('attachment, cv', 'file', 'types'=>'doc, docx, pdf, odt'),
            array('re_password','compare','compareAttribute'=>'password'),

        );
```

When I don't use the scenarios

```
  return array(
                array('first_name, second_name, username, password, email, skype, attachment, just, cv', 'required'),

                array('first_name, second_name, username, password, email, skype, status, attachment, just, cv', 'length', 'max'=>255),
                // The following rule is used by search().
                // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
                array('attachment, cv', 'file', 'types'=>'doc, docx, pdf, odt'),
                array('re_password','compare','compareAttribute'=>'password'),

            );
```

This works but there are some columns that I don't need the one updating to bother with like cv and attachment.

Please show some light because I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set scenario while using your models. There are two ways to do that:

```
$model=new ModelName('SCENARIO_NAME');
```

Or

```
$model=new ModelName();
$model->setScenario('SCENARIO_NAME');
```

Comment: Or just `$model->scenario = "scenario_name"`

Comment: I'm not dear, I'm zebra!

Comment: @Justinas :))) hahaaa, I like this conversation. Anyway, your alternative solution is right :)